# Choosing BLE beacons and gateways

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, tracking-devices, beacons

I don’t get what is the difference between different beacons. For example, the Meeblue M52-SA costs 10 USD, approximately, and the Estimote Proximity beacon costs 25 USD. Both use Bluetooth 5, their battery life is similar and have the same waterproof protection rating. Why does the Estimote beacon cost 2.5x?

If I won’t use the Estimote Proximity SDK, what is the advantage of buying Estimote Proximity beacons? Would I have a better accuracy? Here I have some advantages of using Generic Beacons: https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/GenericBeacons

I think it’s a better idea to use a generic BLE gateway that scans all the BLE signals and a generic API/SDK, based on Android Beacon Library. What do you think? How difficult is to use that API?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? I’m confused by the fact you mention both gateways and beacons and Android. There can be big differences in terms of power output or sensitivity, antenna design, actual battery life with the same parameters, features, and more. On the other hand, prices are freely chosen by manufacturers with different cost structures, so it’s possible there are no useful differences at all. You’ll have to compare them in your actual use case.

Comment: Hi @jcaron. I'm developing an indoor asset tracking. My goal is to have a website (or an application) with the map of the warehouse and each one of the assets (beacons) moving there, so I can find the beacon I want when I need it